# Simple list of sub category

Tags: iphone, arrays, uitableview, dictionary

I have a plist with categories :

```
<array>
<dict>
    <key>part</key>
    <string>up</string>
    <key>house</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>name1</string>
            <key>theme</key>
            <string>theme1</string>
            <key>image</key>
            <string>image1.png</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>part</key>
    <string>down</string>
    <key>house</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>name2</string>
            <key>theme</key>
            <string>theme4</string>
            <key>image</key>
            <string>image2.png</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>name3</string>
            <key>theme</key>
            <string>theme2</string>
            <key>image</key>
            <string>image3.png</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
```

But I would like also have an array with only the list of all the names.
I tried `NSArray* allSecretsWithDuplicates = [data valueForKeyPath:@"part.name"];`
The problem is it return an array of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to walk the structure yourself - write a method that takes in a dictionary, gets values for all keys and when it finds an array calls itself again for each dictionary in the array.  When it comes across a key named "name" have it store the value into either a class local mutable array, or a mutable array that you pass along as you call yourself.